# Micnet and bitnet,do you know them?

Tags: history, net

I like old stuff of 80 and 90's
and sometimes i like to study old technologies(some of them still used..)
like SYSTEMV,SCO-UNIX,Xenix,etc..
Reading a book about Sco Unix on a page i see..

```
mail support uucp and networks like bitnet micnet and 
internet
```

I know internet and uucp,but what are/was bitnet and micnet?

Comment: _some of them still used_ - And some of them re-invented poorly many years later. UUCP being replaced by ETRN, ATRN, and the like is a prime example. On an unrelated topic: "Internet" back then didn't mean what it means today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [BITNET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BITNET), Because It's There (or Time) Network was an inter-university network transferring e-mail and [remote job entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_job_entry) files over leased telephone lines.
- Micnet was a local area network using serial (RS232) lines to link computers running Microsoft's XENIX operating system. See the [XENIX 286 Communications Guide](http://tenox.net/docs/xenix/Intel_XENIX_286_Communications_Guide.pdf).

Comment: Minet supported star and serial topologies and other stuff. I am trying to get it working on an old Lisa.